# API - TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python

All the variables that store the API data:

```
formatted_data = json_data['list'][0]['main'] # Extracting the main description from the API
formatted_data3 = json_data['list'][0]['weather']['description'] # Extracting the weather description from the API
formatted_data2 = json_data['list'][0]['main']['temp'] # Extracting the temperature description from the API
formatted_data4 = json_data['list'][0]['main']['temp_min']
formatted_data5 = json_data['list'][0]['main']['temp_max']
formatted_data6 = json_data['list'][0]['clouds']['all']
```

Can anyone help me out with this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "MainWeatherAPI.py", line 21, in <module>
print(ForecastAPIFunction.getForecast(city, country))
File "/home/codio/workspace/Weatherbot/ForecastAPIFunction.py", line 
13, in getForecast
formatted_data3 = json_data['list'][0]['weather']['description'] 
#Extracting the weather description from the API
```

**EDIT:**

Code that is relevant to what I have tried so far:

```
while True:
    address = input("Address: ")
    if address == 'quit' or address == 'q':
        break
    url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({'address': address}) 
    json_data = requests.get(url).json() 
    #print(url)
    json_status = json_data['status'] print('API Status: ' + json_status + '\n')
    if json_status == 'OK':
        for each in json_data['results'][0]['address_components']:
            print(each['long_name'])
```

**EDIT:**

Sample API data that correlates to all the variables that I have used to store the data. This is also relevant to the error that I am receiving.

```
{
  'cnt': 40, 
  'city': {
    'name': 'Coventry', 
    'country': 'GB', 
    'id': 2652221, 
    'coord': {
      'lat': 52.4066, 
      'lon': -1.5122}
  }, 
  'message': 0.165, 
  'list': [
    {'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 
    'dt_txt': '2017-11-23 21:00:00', 
    'weather': [
      {
        'main': 'Clouds', 
        'icon': '04n', 
        'id': 803, 
        'description': 'broken clouds'
      }
    ], 
    'rain': {}, 
    'main': {
      'temp_max': 278.37,
      'grnd_level': 1005.61, 
      'temp': 278.37, 
      'sea_level': 1018.48,
      'humidity': 79, 
      'temp_kf': 0.15, 
      'pressure': 1005.61, 
      'temp_min': 278.226}, 
      'clouds': {'all': 56}, 
      'dt': 1511470800, 
      'wind': {'deg':''}
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post with a sample of what the JSON data looks like.

Comment: while True:
    address = input("Address: ")
    
    if address == 'quit' or address == 'q':
        break 
    
    url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({'address': address})

    json_data = requests.get(url).json()
    #print(url)

    json_status = json_data['status']
    print('API Status: ' + json_status + '\n')
    
    
    if json_status == 'OK':
        for each in json_data['results'][0]['address_components']:
            print(each['long_name'])

Comment: Change `[:0]` to `[0]`.

Comment: Unfortunately getting same error

Comment: @aaromated as I mentioned in my other comment. Please edit your post with sample output of the JSON data that comes from the API. It will be easier to debug your issues.

Comment: @kstullich done

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
formatted_data3 = json_data['list'][0]['weather'][0]['description']
```

the weather element is array as well

Comment: return "Description: " + formatted_data + ", " + formatted_data3 + "\n" + "Clouds: " + str(formatted_data6) + ("%") + ("\n") +
("Temperature: ") + str(celsius_temp) + "°C" + "\n" + "Average: " + str(celsius_min) + " to " + str(celsius_max) + "°C"
TypeError: Can't convert 'dict' object to str implicitly, would lead to this error

Comment: formatted_data is a dict, so try with, for example formatted_data['temp'] or each of the dict elements separately concatenate to your output string in the similar manner...

Comment: something like this, maybe: return "Description: "  + formatted_data3 + "\n" + "Clouds: " + str(formatted_data6) + ("%") + ("\n") + ("Temperature: ") + str(celsius_temp) + "°C" + "\n" + "Average: " + str(celsius_min) + " to " + str(celsius_max) + "°C"